# How to prevent Google Maps from zooming in

Tags: google-maps

It there a way to prevent Google Maps from zooming in when your search for a city?

[image]

Scenario: When I search for Ocala, FL, it's not because I want a map of Ocala, FL.  It's because I want to know where Ocala, FL is.

Comment: Scenario is dead on and almost always the case. Such a basic function, or lets say "story", of a map. What good is the immediate 400 feet around a location when looking up a list of places around the state?  UI: A lock checkbox somewhere near the zoom buttons... why not G?

Answer (score 3):

This is a real pain point for me too.

I get around the issue by searching for directions between my desired location and a second location that is a suitable distance away. For example, instead of "Ocala, FL" try searching for "[Ocala to Orlando](https://www.google.com.au/maps/dir/Ocala,+FL,+USA/Orlando,+FL,+USA/)" or even "[Ocala to Miami](https://www.google.com.au/maps/dir/Ocala,+FL,+USA/Miami,+FL,+USA/)".

This does require some rudimentary geographical knowledge about the wider area you're searching in, and you'll have to put up with transit information being overlayed on the map, but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible at the moment..

Answer (score 0):

There really is not a way. If you look at the API for Google Maps you will see the when you perform a geocode that the one of the values returned was accuracy http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#Geocoding_Structured

Now the geocoding has types: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#GeocodingAddressTypes which google uses to know what zoom level to zoom in at.